# How to convert algorithm to python

Tags: python, algorithm

new to python and I'm having trouble converting a script to a more effective algorithm I was given.

Here's the python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import itertools
target_sum = 10
a = 1
b = 2
c = 4
a_range = range(0, target_sum + 1, a)
b_range = range(0, target_sum + 1, b)
c_range = range(0, target_sum + 1, c)
for i, j, k in itertools.product(a_range, b_range, c_range):
    if i + j + k == 10:
        print a, ':', i/a, ',', b, ':',  j/b, ',', c, ':',  k/c
```

(it only does 3 variables just for example, but I want to use it on thousands of variables in the end).

Here's the result I am looking for(all the combo's that make it result to 10):

```
1 : 0 , 2 : 1 , 4 : 2
1 : 0 , 2 : 3 , 4 : 1
1 : 0 , 2 : 5 , 4 : 0
1 : 2 , 2 : 0 , 4 : 2
1 : 2 , 2 : 2 , 4 : 1
1 : 2 , 2 : 4 , 4 : 0
1 : 4 , 2 : 1 , 4 : 1
1 : 4 , 2 : 3 , 4 : 0
1 : 6 , 2 : 0 , 4 : 1
1 : 6 , 2 : 2 , 4 : 0
1 : 8 , 2 : 1 , 4 : 0
1 : 10 , 2 : 0 , 4 : 0
```

In question [Can brute force algorithms scale?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7265576/can-brute-force-algorithms-scale) a better algorithm was suggested but I'm having a hard time implementing the logic within python.  The new test code:

```
    # logic to convert
    #for i = 1 to k
    #for z = 0 to sum:
    #    for c = 1 to z / x_i:
    #        if T[z - c * x_i][i - 1] is true:  #having trouble creating the table...not sure if thats a matrix
    #            set T[z][i] to true

#set the variables
sum = 10
data = [1, 2, 4]
# trying to find all the different ways to combine the data to equal the sum

for i in range(len(data)):
    print(i)
    if i == 0:
        continue
    for z in range(sum):
        for c in range(z/i):
            print("*" * 15)
            print('z is equal to: ', z)
            print('c is equal to: ', c)
            print('i is equal to: ', i)
            print(z - c * i)
            print('i - 1: ', (i - 1))

            if (z - c * i) == (i - 1):
                print("(z - c * i) * (i - 1)) match!")
                print(z,i)
```

Sorry its obviously pretty messy, I have no idea how to generate a table in the section that has:

```
if T[z - c * x_i][i - 1] is true:
    set T[z][i] to true
```

In other places while converting the algo, I had more problems because in lines like 'or i = 1 to k' converting it to python gives me an error saying "TypeError: 'int' object is not utterable"

Comment: Are you working with Python 3? If you're working with Python 2, do `print foo` rather than `print(foo)`.

Comment: It's not wrong to use `print(foo)` in Python 2.x, so if he likes it, don't tell him not to use it!  I do that a lot of the time myself when posting here.

Comment: Well Chris..I wrote this in python2 but eventually will work on changing it to python3(right now I'm a bit more familiar with python2 but I tried to be as python3-ish as possible for a newbie :-)

Comment: The line c in range(z/i) is not correct -- try range(int(z/i))

Comment: `index_accumulator.append([lol[i][indices[i]] for i in range(len(lol))])` is more idiomatically spelled `index_accumulator.append(l[index] for l, index in zip(lol, indices)])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get that block which creates the table for dynamic programming with this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

# T[x, i] is True if 'x' can be solved
# by a linear combination of data[:i+1]
T = defaultdict(bool)           # all values are False by default
T[0, 0] = True                # base case

for i, x in enumerate(data):    # i is index, x is data[i]
    for s in range(sum + 1):
        for c in range(s / x + 1):
            if T[s - c * x, i]:
                T[s, i + 1] = True
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, rm.  I updated my question to show the output.  Basically I simplified my existing script, but I am trying to get the same output as the answer in the link in my question.

Comment: updated - you'll still need to use this table to get back the answers you want, this will just have a `True` at `T[(sum, len(data))]` if solutions exist.

Comment: `T[a, b]` is neater than `T[(a, b)]`.

Comment: @Chris, yes, thank you. Should have noticed that.  `,` makes tuples, not parentheses.

Comment: @Chris Actually I like the explicit `tuple` better here, my brain parses it like multiple arguments to a function otherwise. Nice answer rm.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the table you need with a list of lists:

```
t = [[False for i in range(len(data))] for z in range(sum)] #Creates table filled with 'False'

for i in range(len(data)):
    print(i)
    if i == 0:
        continue
    for z in range(sum):
        for c in range(int(z/i)):
            print("*" * 15)
            print('z is equal to: ', z)
            print('c is equal to: ', c)
            print('i is equal to: ', i)
            print(z - c * i)
            print('i - 1: ', (i - 1))

            if (z - c * i) == (i - 1):
                print("(z - c * i) * (i - 1)) match!")
                t[z][i] = True     # Sets element in table to 'True'
```

As for your TypeError, you can't say i = 1 to k, you need to say: `for i in range(1,k+1):` (assuming you want `k` to be included).

Another tip is that you shouldn't use `sum` as a variable name, because this is already a built-in python function. Try putting `print sum([10,4])` in your program somewhere!

Comment: That should be `for i in range(1, k+1)`.

Comment: @Keith Cheers, one never grows out of off-by-one errors it would seem!