# Unable to implement a dynamic programming table algorithm in python

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am having problems creating a table in python.  Basically I want to build a table that for every number tells me if I can use it to break down another(its the table algo from the accepted answer in [Can brute force algorithms scale?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7265576/can-brute-force-algorithms-scale)). Here's the pseudo code:

```
for i = 1 to k
    for z = 0 to sum:
        for c = 1 to z / x_i:
            if T[z - c * x_i][i - 1] is true:
                set T[z][i] to true
```

Here's the python implementation I have:

```
from collections import defaultdict


data = [1, 2, 4]
target_sum = 10

# T[x, i] is True if 'x' can be solved
# by a linear combination of data[:i+1]
T = defaultdict(bool)           # all values are False by default
T[0, 0] = True                # base case


for i, x in enumerate(data):    # i is index, x is data[i]
    for s in range(target_sum + 1): #set the range of one higher than sum to include sum itself
        for c in range(s / x + 1):  
            if T[s - c * x, i]:
                T[s, i+1] = True

#query area   
target_result = 1
for node in T:
    if node[0]==target_result:
        print node, ':', T[node]
```

So what I expect is if `target_result` is set to 8, it shows how each item in list `data` can be used to break that number down. For 8, 1,2,4 for all work so I expect them all to be true, but this program is making everything true.  For example, 1 should only be able to be broken down by 1(and not 2 or 4) but when I run it as 1, I get:

```
(1, 2) : True
(1, 0) : False
(1, 3) : True
(1, 1) : True
```

can anyone help me understand what's wrong with the code? or perhaps I am not understanding the algorithm that was posted in answer I am referring to.

(Note: I could be completely wrong, but I learned that defaultdict creates entries even if its not there, and if the entry exists the algo turns it to true, maybe thats the problem I'm not sure, but it was the line of thought I tried to go but it didn't work for me because it seems to break the overall implemention)
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code works if you print the solution using [`RecursivelyListAllThatWork()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7265593/4279):

```
coeff = [0]*len(data)
def RecursivelyListAllThatWork(k, sum): # Using last k variables, make sum
    # /* Base case: If we've assigned all the variables correctly, list this
    # * solution.
    # */
    if k == 0:
        # print what we have so far
        print(' + '.join("%2s*%s" % t for t in zip(coeff, data)))
        return
    x_k = data[k-1]
    # /* Recursive step: Try all coefficients, but only if they work. */
    for c in range(sum // x_k + 1):
       if T[sum - c * x_k, k - 1]:
           # mark the coefficient of x_k to be c
           coeff[k-1] = c
           RecursivelyListAllThatWork(k - 1, sum - c * x_k)
           # unmark the coefficient of x_k
           coeff[k-1] = 0

RecursivelyListAllThatWork(len(data), target_sum)
```

#### [Output](http://ideone.com/IsaN4)

```
10*1 +  0*2 +  0*4
 8*1 +  1*2 +  0*4
 6*1 +  2*2 +  0*4
 4*1 +  3*2 +  0*4
 2*1 +  4*2 +  0*4
 0*1 +  5*2 +  0*4
 6*1 +  0*2 +  1*4
 4*1 +  1*2 +  1*4
 2*1 +  2*2 +  1*4
 0*1 +  3*2 +  1*4
 2*1 +  0*2 +  2*4
 0*1 +  1*2 +  2*4
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works!  I was trying to break the problem into parts and work on it, but guess I needed the whole thing(I thought the table would look differently).  I'll play around with it, but it looks like I can run the table generation on one machine and then have other machines use the generated table and RecursivelyListAllThatWork to scale it.  I'll test it but thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

As a side note, you don't really need a `defaultdict` with what you're doing, you can use a normal `dict` + `.get()`:

```py
data = [1, 2, 4]
target_sum = 10

T = {}
T[0, 0] = True

for i,x in enumerate(data):
    for s in range(target_sum + 1):    # xrange on python-2.x
        for c in range(s // x + 1):
            if T.get((s - c * x, i)):
                T[s, i+1] = True
```

If you're using J.S. solution, don't forget to change:

```
if T[sum - c * x_k, k - 1]:
```

with:

```
if T.get((sum - c * x_k, k - 1)):
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out.  Just wondering(I'm new to python) is it better to avoid importing functions that you can create on your own or is it better to import?  I thought maybe importing maybe not good for memory usage, but also the person who made the library may have made it more efficient.  I'm a bit conflicted, so not sure which is better.

Comment: @Lostsoul: No no, don't avoid it. If you're building a program you've already a lot of things to worry about, if someone else provide you something that can help you, use that! One thing less to worry about. He'll be the one maintaining that thing for you. Keep also in mind that premature optimizations is the root of (most) evil. First get things to work, and only after take a look at where you have performance/memory issue. You may want to take a look at this [Perfomrance Tips](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips).

Answer (score 1):

Your code is *right*.

1 = 1 * 1 + 0 * 2, so T[1, 2] is True.

1 = 1 * 1 + 0 * 2 + 0 * 4, so T[1, 3] is True.

As requested in the comments, a short explanation of the algo:
It calculates all numbers from 0 to `targetsum` that can be represented as a sum of (non-negative) multiples of some of the numbers in `data`. 
If `T[s, i]` is `True`, then s can be represented in this way using only the first `i` elements of `data`.

At the start, 0 can be represented as the empty sum, thus `T[0, 0]` is `True`. (This step may seem a little technical.)
Let `x` be the 'i+1'-th element of data. Then, the algorithm tries for each number `s` if it can be represented by the sum of some multiple of `x` and a number for which a representation exists that uses only the first `i` elements of data (the existence of such a number means `T[s - c * x, i]` is `True` for some `c`). If so, `s` can be represented using only the first `i+1` elements of `data`.

Comment: then I must not understand the algo.  I thought the last number(in your case, 2 and 3) represented the location on the datalist of the variable to use. Just to clarify, what do the numbers mean(I think I did not interprete them correctly)? You get the same result when you change 1 to 8 also..

Comment: 2 (and 3) mean "you can use the first 2 (or 3) elements of data", not "use only elements number 2 (or 3)".